# Using CocoaPods stops iOS build using ionic Project

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I have created an ionic Project. I build the app and its working perfectly using Ionic CIL. Now using cocoapods, I created a pod file and loadded the required pods and did pod install.

Now when I try to run ionic run/build ios, I get this error:
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig

Command failed with exit code 2

Please help me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that causes the build to fail is that once you start using CocoaPods you have to build the project .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj.

I created a plugin that makes supporting CocoaPods simple by just adding a in your config.xml or plugin.xml. The plugin handles the creation of the Podfile and fixes the build scripts used by the ios platform.

Check it out https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support. to support fo swift also, Update to version 1.2.5 of the plugin and add the following to the ios platform section of your config.xml

```
<preference name="pods_ios_min_version" value="8.0"/>
<preference name="pods_use_frameworks" value="true"/>
```

Comment: if any once have better option pleasse suggest

Comment: If you are using Ionic2 with Firebase Auth and building for iOS via Xcode, do you have to use Cocoa Pods?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736623/google-firebase-authentication-no-displayname-or-photourl-for-ios

Comment: I am not used Ionic 2 with cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your iOS platform and then add the 5.0.0 version like this:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@5.0.0
```

Hope that helps.